# How to create a temporary table with a column containing special characters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, special-characters

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I need to create a temporary table which will have only one column containing a list of special characters.

My `T-SQL` query stands as follows:

```
USE [MyDatabase]

create table #t1 
( 
    
    SpecialCharacters nvarchar (255) NOT NULL
    
); 

INSERT INTO #t1

VALUES ( 

'@',
'&',
'\',
'?',
'/',
':',
';',
'.',
',',
'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
)
```

When running the above codes, I get the following error message: `"Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."`

What is the wrong with the code?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `VALUES` clause has 20 columns, but your table `SpecialCharacters` only has 1 columns. The error is telling you the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
create table #t1 
( 
    SpecialCharacters char(1) NOT NULL
); 

INSERT INTO #t1(SpecialCharacters)
VALUES 
('@'),
('&'),
('\'),
('?'),
('/'),
(':'),
(';'),
('.'),
(','),
('0'),
('1'),
('2'),
('3'),
('4'),
('5'),
('6'),
('7'),
('8'),
('9');
```

While the column name `[SpecialCharacters]` is not required, it's better to be explicit.